# Difference of two digit square numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So I've just bought a math notebook for the summer and I've encountered a problem that seems very simple but I can't find its solution. It says as following:

Prove the fact that there is not a integer written as $100a+10b+c$ that can be also written as $(10a+b)^2 - (10b+c)^2$ , where  $0 < a,b < 10$ and $-1 < c < 10$

Comment: Is this what you meant? $\mathbf{100 \times a + 10\times b + c}$ cannot be written as $\mathbf{{(10\times a) + b}^2 - {(10\times b) + c}^2}$

Comment: Are the $a,b,c$ in the penultimate line the same as the last line?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Yes

Comment: @UmashankarS And yes indeed

Comment: @UmashankarS You messed up the parenthesis.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Do you have any suggestions on how I could resolve this?

Comment: I know, I can't fix it, but I understood the question anyway

Comment: @DavidT. Don't know if this helps, but the LHS is always a number between 110 and 999, so you're left with proving the RHS never coincides with this set

Answer (score 1):

The equation

$$100a+10b+c=(10a+b)^2-(10b+c)^2$$

shows that $c+c^2=b^2$ (mod $10$)

since $c+c^2$ can only be $0,2,6$ (mod $10$), $b^2=0,2,6$ (mod $10$)

this in turn implies that $b$ is either equal to $4$ or $6$

now multiply by $4$ and factor the given equation as follows

$$(2c+20a+22b-9)(2c-20a+18b+11)=(40b-99)$$

for $b=4$ we get

$$(79+20 a+2 c)(83-20 a+2 c)=61$$

which is impossible since the first factor is more than $79$ so the product cannot equal $61$

for $b=6$ we get

$$(123+20 a+2 c)(119-20 a+2 c)=141$$

which is again not possible since the first factor is more than $142$

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion**

Try to use $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y)$ to figure out what the last digit must be.